# Proper etiquette for background images

Tags: html, css, background

I created a black and white collage consisting of a number of images - but saved the file as  1280*1024 - ideally encompassing that rez of a screen.

The issue is, would it be wiser to have the background scale, and stretch the images in the case of a larger screen or should I have it repeat so as not to lose resolution, and have smaller screens cropped from some of the background?

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally don't think scaling an image up is ever an option. It's incredibly noticeable, and it doesn't look good.  I would recommend using a background image that at least works on 1920 x 1080, and gracefully fade out the image on the edges or tiles well so if someone sees the page on an even larger screen, there aren't strong lines on the edges of the background.

If you are concerned about the bandwidth involved in large images, check out [CSS3 Media Queries](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries). All mobile browsers support this CSS3 module, and it will allow you to target certain resolutions and send them smaller images (both in dimensions and file size).

If your image does tile well, I would recommend going with the smallest pattern, and letting css do the repetition for you. There's no point in pushing more pixels down the pipe than necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It's up to the user really but they obviously can't make that decision. I'd scale it but that's not as easy as tiling it. I've never successfully scaled a background image.

Answer (score 1):

It will also depend on your preference.

Are you okay with having a stretched image as a background, in case the user has a larger screen? If yes, then by all means set the background image to stretch. Or, are you more keen on preserving the integrity of the image? In the latter case, it's much better to have the image tile.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in creating a full page background image, try one of these techniques found on CSS Tricks: "[Perfect Full Page Background Image](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)".